# How do you fire change or click event based on a condition set by v-select?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a v-select field that can choose between user types. When a user type is selected, the v-model changes to that type.
I would like to create a method that fires a message when a specific user type is selected, BUT I do not want it to pop up every time the user opens the page if the v-model is set to that type of user.

```
      <w-v-select
        v-model="user.type"
        :options="userTypeOptions"
        @change="displayMessage()"
        :reduce="option => option.type"
        :clearable="false"
      />

data() {
  return {
      user: {
        type: 'DEFAULT'
    }
  };
}

  userTypeOptions() {
    return userTypes
      .map(userType => ({type: userType, label: this.$t(`model.user.types.${userType}`)}))
      .sort((a, b) => a.label.localeCompare(b.label));
  },
```

And then I need a method like:

```
  displayMessage(){
    if ( ** user clicks on type that equals "ADMIN" **) {
      console.log('You have clicked on ADMIN')
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple so

```
methods: {
  displayMessage(){
    if (this.user.type == "ADMIN" ) {
      console.log('You have clicked on ADMIN')
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since you call your function in the `@change` event, it will not be called every time. Check the playground below.

The other way to achieve the same result would be using a [`watcher`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html)

```js
const App = {
  data() {
    return {      
      user: {
        type: "ADMIN"
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
   displayMessage(){
      if (this.user.type == "ADMIN" ) {
        console.log('You have clicked on ADMIN')
      }
    }  
  }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
li.active { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
<select v-model="user.type" @change="displayMessage">
  <option value="DEFAULT">DEFAULT</option>
  <option value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
</select>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tolbxela, but won't this message be displayed every time a user enters the page if user type is set to ADMIN? I only want it to happen when the actual selection takes place.

Comment: No, please check the update.